# To have the DAG always ON , Used is_paused_upon_creation . It's not working

Tags: airflow

I have used `is_paused_upon_creation=False` as below but it threw an error as below

`__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_paused_upon_creation'`

```
dag = DAG(
    DAG_ID,
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=SCHEDULE_INTERVAL,
    start_date=START_DATE,
    is_paused_upon_creation=False
)
```

Comment: which version of airflow are you using?

Comment: Also, the default value of is_paused_upon_creation is False

Comment: 1.10.3 Version ..

Comment: I just wrote a simple dag and checked is_paused_upon_creation with airflow 1.10.7 and it works without any error, can you share your whole code?

Comment: The code is in this link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62293024/airflow-log-cleanup-need-help-on-jinja-variable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As rightly [sensed by **@Binoy J**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62294167/to-have-the-dag-always-on-used-is-paused-upon-creation-its-not-working#comment110175587_62294167), it is Airflow version problem

- The [`is_paused_upon_creation` param](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/dag.py#L173) was added in [#5473](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/5473) to patch [Airflow-4844](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-4844)
- And [Airflow-4844](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-4844) went live in [v1.10.4](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html#airflow-1-10-4-2019-08-06)